# From a shell script to an application icon

Tags: .desktop, startup-applications

I'm trying to make an icon (later in Application) for a software that I just downloaded.
I unziped the .tar.gz. The unziped file contains bin and share directories.
The bin directory contains the shell script for the application. (runs on terminal)
I created the .desktop file as follows (in /~)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=CopasiUI
Exec=/home/ubuntu/Documents/Biologie/L3SV/S6/PPD/Copasi/bin/CopasiUI.sh
Icon=/home/ubuntu/Documents/Biologie/L3SV/S6/PPD/Copasi/share/copasi/Copasi48-alpha.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

I'm new in ubuntu and I feel the lack of knowledge in that matter.
From there it does not work yet. I get "There was an error launching the app" 
Does not even show the icon I selected. 
Can i just keep the `.desktop` file in `~` to see if it's working?

Thank you for your answers.

(It worked without the .sh)

Comment: Did you make the .desktop file executable (run `chmod +x /path/to/file.desktop`)? You can try to install the desktop launcher with `sudo desktop-file-install /path/to/file.desktop`. It will also appear in the dash as application then and have a copy of the .desktop file stored in /usr/share/applications.

Comment: @ByteCommander better not store a `.desktop` file globally if the application is stored locally. Use `~/.local/share/applications` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your script both starts with the Shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) and is marked as executable, you'll need to run `sh` specifying the shell script as an argument in order to execute it: this line:

```
Exec=/home/ubuntu/Documents/Biologie/L3SV/S6/PPD/Copasi/bin/CopasiUI.sh
```

Should be this line:

```
Exec=sh /home/ubuntu/Documents/Biologie/L3SV/S6/PPD/Copasi/bin/CopasiUI.sh
```

Comment: @JacobVlijm True, i clarified it